# oracle sql how to match name split through 3 columns?

Tags: sql, oracle

This database is not mine so i cannot alter it to a single name column (unfortunately).

```
**table1:**

name1,name2,name3
john,mega,rambo
john,master,travolta
john,super,connor
```

i'm sending query string $qs to a php file via ajax
file.php?qs=john%rambo

i want it to query the oracle database and return the name "John MEga Rambo", so i thought this would work but it doesn't:

**SQL:**

```
SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT(name1,name2),name3) as name 
  FROM table1 
 WHERE name LIKE '%{$qs}%'
```

I guess the biggest problem here is that someone can search by `name1` or `name2` / `name1` or `name3`. Any ideas ?

Comment: It's always helpful to be more specific than "doesn't work".  Descriptions of how a piece of code doesn't work, what errors it throws, etc. are very helpful.  The code you posted would have a syntax error but without the error message to confirm that, it's really hard to know whether you made a transcription error.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is generally not very helpful, please provide actual errors or incorrect behaviour. Your table doesn't have a `name` column; you seem to want to search for the value existing any of the three columns - but not sure what you last paragraphs means, as that suggests combinatins of columns?

Comment: you guys are right about that, i'll have that in consideration next time i post a question, thank you!

Comment: just for the record, i was getting oracle error 904 invalid identifier which makes sense since the identifier wasn't a selected column in the queried table. Using the HAVING clause resulted in the same error

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you're getting an invalid identifier error. You can't referance a column alias in the same level of query it's defined (except in `order by`), because of the order the query is parsed and executed.

You could use a CTE or an inline view (subquery):

```
SELECT name
FROM (
  SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT(name1,name2),name3) as name 
  FROM table1 
)
WHERE name LIKE '%{$qs}%'
```

With some dummy data:

```
create table table1 (name1 varchar2(10), name2 varchar2(10), name3 varchar2(10));
insert into table1 (name1, name2, name3) values ('john', 'mega', 'rambo');
insert into table1 (name1, name2, name3) values ('john', 'master', 'travolta');
insert into table1 (name1, name2, name3) values ('john', 'super', 'connor');
```

that query - with `{$qs}` replaced with `rambo` - gets:

```
NAME                          
------------------------------
johnmegarambo
```

As you can see `concat` won't automatically add whitespace, so you might find the concatenation operator easier:

```
SELECT name
FROM (
  SELECT name1 ||' '|| name2 ||' '|| name3 as name 
  FROM table1 
)
WHERE name LIKE '%{$qs}%'

NAME                            
--------------------------------
john mega rambo
```

But if you're looking for more exact matches you might want to check each column instead:

```
SELECT name1 ||' '|| name2 ||' '|| name3 as name 
FROM table1 
WHERE name1 = '{$qs}'
OR name2 = '{$qs}'
OR name3 = '{$qs}'
```

Maybe you want the flexibility to search for partial matches though.

As a further consideration, by default you can only search for values exactly matching the case of the search string - so with your data, searching for `RAMBO` wouldn't find a match. There are a couple of ways around that if it's an issue for you.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Alex Poole for the replies, those didn't quite solve the problem BUT it pointed me in the right direction! It seems like oracle is a little bit picky with syntax, so a simple HAVING that would work in MySQL won't work on oracle. I'll post both solutions for ORACLE and MySQL

**MySQL:**

```
SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT(name1,name2),name3) AS name
 FROM table1 
HAVING name LIKE '{%$qs}%'
```

**ORACLE**

```
WITH table1 as ( SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT(name1,name2),name3) as name
 FROM table1)
            select * from table1 where name like '%{$qs}%'
```

Comment: If your CTE works then the inline view/subquery I showed will too - they're essentially the same if you only reference it once. Feel free to comment on my answer to say why it didn't work for you. But... your question doesn't mention MySQL or `having`?

Comment: I will post the error message later when i get the chance, i only mentioned mysql because it's what i usually use, posted both answers just because why not :)